# how to rename Request and response files generated by wire-mock Proxy server(node.js) in mapping and __file folder

Tags: wiremock-standalone

Can anyone tell me how to rename Request and response files generated by wire-mock Proxy server(node.js) in mapping and __file folder .

I Tried creating Wiremock config file and js file to rename these files but its not working .